# When saving as a JPEG, illustrator keeps cutting parts of my artboard off

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, artboard

I created a graphic in Illustrator, and there is a lot of white space around the graphic itself, but it is all within the artboard. When I got to export my piece as a JPEG, Illustrator does whatever it wants with the white space; cuts it off, adds more??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Saving as JPG... use the **Asset Export Window**

- Select all the illustration components and drag them to the window holding
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Check the JPG export settings if necessary launching the **Export for Screen Dialog** icon at the bottom
- Click the **Export** button

[image: Asset Export Window]

Answer (score 1):

By default, Illustrator will only export the exact borders of the "artwork" on the artboard, be it smaller or bigger than the artboard.

In order to use your artboard borders when exporting, make sure to select **Use Artboards** in the *Export* dialog.

[image: Export Dialog]

Additionally, you can use **File → Save for Web** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) instead, there you can also choose to use the artboard.

[image: Save for Web]